# SwiftyJSON parse json query

Tags: ios, json, swift3, xcode8, swifty-json

I am writing a code in swift 3 for parse a query in json format result from http request.

the json format is:

```
JSON: {
base = stations;
coord =     {
    lat = "23.9";
    lon = "42.89";
};
weather =     (
            {
        description = mist;
        icon = 50n;
        id = 701;
        main = Mist;
    },
            {
        description = fog;
        icon = 50n;
        id = 741;
        main = Fog;
    }
);
wind =     {
    deg = "222.506";
    speed = "1.72";
};}
```

My code is:

```
Alamofire.request(url).responseJSON { response in

        if let a = response.result.value  {

            let jsonVar = JSON(a)

            if let resDati = jsonVar["base"].string {
                print(resDati as String)  // <- OK
            }

            if let dati2 = jsonVar["weather"].array {

                for item in dati2 {

                    print(" > \(item["main"])") // <- OK

                }

            }

        } else {
            print(Error.self)
        }

    }
```

The problem is on "coord" and "wind" data i have try:

```
if let dati4 = jsonVar["wind"].array {

    for item in dati4 {

        print("-- \(item)")

    } }
```

I cannot print the data relatives to "wind" and "coord" in json format.

How can I resolve this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key `wind` contains a dictionary, not an array, you can get the `deg` and `speed` values using SwiftyJSON with this code:

```
if let wind = jsonVar["wind"].dictionary,
    let deg = wind["deg"]?.double,
    let speed = wind["speed"]?.double {
    print(deg, speed)
}
```

`coord` works accordingly

```
if let coord = jsonVar["coord"].dictionary,
    let lat = coord["lat"]?.double,
    let lon = coord["lon"]?.double {
    print(lat, lon)
}
```

Note: All values are of type `Double`, *the json format* is misleading.

Comment: I write your code but the result of 'deg' and 'speed' is nil.

Comment: If `jsonVar["base"]` prints something (`<- OK`), my code is supposed to work. too.

Comment: i have added your code at mine and in console it print the 'base' and the 'weather' but not 'wind', so i have shift 'let deg' and 'let speed' from 'if' and in console i see 'nil nil'.

Comment: Then the JSON you've posted (which is actually not JSON) is wrong. According to the dump `weather` and `wind` are on the same level and both values are strings.

Comment: Thank you for your time.

Comment: However i post the link where i put the Json query: http://openweathermap.org/current

Comment: Indeed the *JSON* is misleading. I updated the answer.